# Reading drive Volume Name into R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to perform a task within R based on the Drive Volume Name/Label, however, I can't figure out how to read the drive label in as a variable. I'm not looking for the letter like C:. I need the actual name of the mounted drive, "Bills Computer". Any ideas???

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, something like this should work:

```
shell("vol C:", intern = TRUE)
```

After that you can parse the volume name from the output string like that:

```
s <- shell("vol C:", intern = TRUE)[1]
substring(s, regexpr('is', s) + 3)
```

Comment: That worked great. You just saved me a lot of work. I really appreciate your help. Have a great day.